# How to use LinkedIn Organization Search API if I do not have redirect URL or any app?

Tags: python, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to get information about profiles of companies in a particular region using the OAuth 2.0 LinkedIn Organisation Search API and Python. It seems it requires me to enter redirect URL which I do not have. So, I am stuck here. Any code snippet or workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

You can use a site like [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/), where you can create an url that will show you the content for any postbacks sent to it.

You can set one of these urls as your redirect url, then you can implement the auth process and check the cookies that were returned and use them on your requests to the api.

I haven't tested this on the linkedin api, it's just an educated guess.